# Select element not working

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a really simple code I just wrote that gets a color value from a select element and uses it to set the border color of elements in a specific class, it doesn't seem to work though though. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<select id="colorSelect" onChange="changeColor()">
    <option value="#000000" selected="selected">Black</option>
    <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
    <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
</select>
```

There are more options in the same format as Red and Blue, but I left them out to save space.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function changeColor
{
    var picker    = document.getElementById("colorSelect");
    var colorName = picker.options[picker.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementByClassName("bordered").style.backGroundColor=colorName;
}
```

Comment: Well, you're missing a parameter list for `changeColor`. Make sure you give us code that works, so that we can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple issues,

The first is you're missing the `()` in your function declaration, it should be:

```
function changeColor() { 

}
```

The second thing is `getElementByClassName` is `getElementsByClassName` (notice the "s" at the end of Elements) - and this will return a collection, so you must specify the index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bordered")[0].style.backGroundColor=colorName;
```

Also, (thanks @AmmarCSE for seeing this) - the `style` property you're after is `backgroundColor` - not `backGroundColor` (JS is VERY case sensitive)

Another important note would be to always have the console open when developing, you'll be able to see what errors are occurring and where. (Usually F12 to open the console on most browsers)

Comment: Thanks alot man, this was one of my first times writing in JavaScript, you got my code working though.